# php - different variables with string, one array

Tags: php

Here are my variables:

```
$a = Hello Mister
$b = I play basketball
$c = You walk in the city
$d = My name is Mary
$e = Where is Bryan
```

I tried of course the explode " ", but it does not work because each variable has words with spaces.
I also tried to adapt the chunk_split and the str_split, without success.
(...)

Comment: $variables=array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add variables in array separated by comma, see example below:

```
$arr = array($a, $b, $c);
```

Or you can also append newly found variable as below :

```
$arr[] = $d;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

- Keep the variable names in an array, like this:

  ```
  $varArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
  ```
- Create an empty result array, like this:

  ```
  $resultArray = array();
  ```
- Loop through this variable array `$varArray` using `foreach` loop. In each iteration use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to get the string and append it to the result array `$resultArray`, like this:

  ```
  foreach($varArray as $v){
      $resultArray[] = $$v;
  }
  ```

Here's the complete code:

```
$a = 'Hello Mister';
$b = 'I play basketball';
$c = 'You walk in the city';
$d = 'My name is Mary';
$e = 'Where is Bryan';

$varArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$resultArray = array();

foreach($varArray as $v){
    $resultArray[] = $$v;
}

// display $resultArray
var_dump($resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that very simply.

```
$a = "Hello Mister";
$b = "I play basketball";
$c = "You walk in the city";
$d = "My name is Mary";
$e = "Where is Bryan";

$sentence = array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);

// or index can be assigned manually
$sentence[0] = $a;
$sentence[1] = $b;
$sentence[2] = $c;
$sentence[3] = $d;

// you can add new variable like below. And indexing automatically maintain sequence by itself.



$sentence[]  = $e;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($sentence);
echo "</pre>";
```

`// output 
Array
(
    [0] => Hello Mister
    [1] => I play basketball
    [2] => You walk in the city
    [3] => My name is Mary
    [4] => Where is Bryan
)`

If you have any further query regarding this you can ask fell free. Thanks